# Is Docker Machine necessary on Ubuntu machines?

Tags: docker

I'm working with Docker and I noticed Windows and MacOS users supposed to use Docker Machine software as well. Do I understand it correctly that for Linux users Docker Machine is optional or unnecessary?

I'm asking because I'll be soon working with AWS and up until now I used Docker Machine to deploy app onto AWS. I understand Docker Machine is the engine that powers Docker as a whole but does it on Linux means I can just download and install Docker from public repository and don't need Docker Machine like Windows or MacOS users do?

Comment: I used Docker on Windows 10 for a 16-month job, and I didn't install or use Docker Machine. I expect this is because Windows 10 allows Docker to run natively, rather than needing an intermediate VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is required to run Docker. Since Ubuntu is Linux, you don't need the Docker Machine to run Docker containers.